# Configure Multicompany in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

Whats the correct way to configure multicompany in openerp?Do we have to always set a parent company or just need to define all the companies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to define one parent company and it's child companies.

This [Multi-Company COnfiguration](http://www.serpentcs.com/serpentcs-multi-company-configuration-in-openerpv7) blog may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You Have to Create One Parent Company for multi Company Environment. and rest Companies will be Child Company.
Parent Company Used To make relation between child Companies.
Parent Company is a dummy Company.